# Error_not _authorised(play services)

Tags: google-play-services, clientid

My Game is published, due to accidental deletion of my client id in cloud console which is linked in-game services creating a great mess now; is there any solution to unlink with client id which is deleted or, can I retrieve deleted client id

Note: I have multiple client ids in one project and all linked with my game, so I deleted 2 out of 3 and now the existing client id is too linked, but it's not working and I'm getting this issue now.

> ```
> [Play Games Plugin DLL] 09/11/18 15:38:51 +05:30 DEBUG: Activating PlayGamesPlatform.
> [Play Games Plugin DLL] 09/11/18 15:38:51 +05:30 DEBUG: PlayGamesPlatform activated: GooglePlayGames.PlayGamesPlatform
> [Play Games Plugin DLL] 09/11/18 15:38:51 +05:30 DEBUG: Creating platform-specific Play Games client.
> [Play Games Plugin DLL] 09/11/18 15:38:51 +05:30 DEBUG: Creating Android IPlayGamesClient Client
> [Play Games Plugin DLL] 09/11/18 15:38:51 +05:30 DEBUG: Starting Auth Transition. Op: SIGN_IN status: ERROR_NOT_AUTHORIZED
> [Play Games Plugin DLL] 09/11/18 15:38:51 +05:30 DEBUG: Invoking callbacks, AuthState changed from silentPending to Unauthenticated.
> [Play Games Plugin DLL] 09/11/18 15:38:51 +05:30 DEBUG: there are pending auth callbacks - starting AuthUI
> [Play Games Plugin DLL] 09/11/18 15:38:51 +05:30 DEBUG: AuthState == Unauthenticated calling auth callbacks with failure
> [Play Games Plugin DLL] 09/11/18 15:38:51 +05:30 DEBUG: Invoking user callback on game thread
> ```

Answer (score 0):

If your application is using client id generated via Google Developers Console and deleted that one, you have to create a new id and recompile your application. 
Follow the steps here on how to [Set Up Google Play Game Services](https://developers.google.com/games/services/console/enabling#step_1_sign_in_to_the_dev_console).

For more information, you can also check the documentation about requesting a data deletion from [Google Analytics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/userdeletion/v3/).